# Characters in row 3 & 4 are moved to the right in 16x4 LCD - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi4, wiringpi

I'm trying to make a simple c++ code to display 4 text contents, each in 4 separate rows. I'm using the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Buster), WiringPi 2.52 and 16x4 LCD Display(5v - 1604A LCD screen).

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <lcd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define LCD_RS 30 //reset pin
#define LCD_E 10  //enable pin 
#define LCD_D4 23 //data pin 4
#define LCD_D5 22 //data pin 5
#define LCD_D6 21 //data pin 6
#define LCD_D7 14 //data pin 7

int lcd;

int main()
{
    wiringPiSetup();
    lcd = lcdInit(4, 20, 4, LCD_RS, LCD_E, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    lcdPosition(lcd, 0, 0);
    lcdPuts(lcd, "Test Row 1");
    lcdPosition(lcd, 0, 1);
    lcdPuts(lcd, "Test Row 2");
    lcdPosition(lcd, 1, 2);
    lcdPuts(lcd, "Test Row 3");
    lcdPosition(lcd, 1, 3);
    lcdPuts(lcd, "Test Row 4");
    cout << "LCD Displays" << endl;
    sleep(30);
    lcdClear(lcd);
    cout << "LCD Clear" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run this code, it shows the result perfectly in line 1 & 2 in LCD Display except line 3 & 4.

I've put the result below to get an idea.

[image: End Result in LCD Display]

From the above image, the first two lines are print perfectly, but in line 3 & 4, when I trying to print them in column 2, it prints in column 6 (`lcdPosition(lcd, 5, 2)`). I can't figure out the exact reason of this problem. Can someone help me to figure this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but you have a 16x4 display but your lcdInit call specifies 20 columns.

```
 lcd = lcdInit(4, 20, 4, LCD_RS, LCD_E, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

try changing that to 16

```
 lcd = lcdInit(4, 16, 4, LCD_RS, LCD_E, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Digging into code this seems like a bug in lcd.c from WiringPi. I found people [discussing similar issues](https://github.com/lincomatic/LiquidTWI2/issues/15) on another library and looking at the code in [lcd.c:84](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/devLib/lcd.c#L84) it has the same offset and seems to have no handling for 16 vs 20 cols.

As WiringPi is [deprecated](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/) I leave this up to the individual developer how to best fix.

Comment: yeah, I've change it to 16 also. But still getting the error.

Comment: Well I seem to remember reading that 4 row displays are a bit odd and hacky extension to 2 row. Without data sheet for the display we can't really help more.

Comment: What do you mean by data sheet for the display? You mean the pin layout?

Comment: A datasheet explaining the command interface, so that it can be checked against the code in the LCD library to make sure it is doing the right thing.

Comment: since I'm new to this thing, I've uploaded the images of pinout, gpio readall & compile/run.

1) Compile & Run
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KTdS9Ne08JtbcVyKchYSMkfJNgQsHYz0/view?usp=sharing

2) GPIO READALL
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Df8-Q5oPmf5jYQIlwolK7Bpil39cPtZC/view?usp=sharing

3) PINOUT
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1euonCFJ1-Zq5J1Vz_CLupsuqk9xuIND1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yeah. it's deprecated. Now I saw it. I'll look into another alternative. Anyways, thank you very much for the support.

Comment: @SriyanArosha If this is a one off project i would probably just change the offset in lcd.c to fit my display and be happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my 16x4 display, but I rezolved it.
I declared the start point to -4 digits for the row 3 and 4.
The library accept negative pozition for start.
Here is my code that works well for 16x4 display

```
//lcd.setCursor(4,0);
//lcd.print("CNC-Pro");
//lcd.setCursor(3,1);
//lcd.print("Plasma THC");
//lcd.setCursor(-4,2);
//lcd.print("Andrei");
//lcd.setCursor(-4,3);
//lcd.print("Apr 2023");
```

[16x4 display 3 and 4 row corectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNHyp.jpg)